# Nested polymorphic relationships CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic relationship between Responses and Posts, Calls & Meetings:

```
 class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :responseable, polymorphic: true
    ...
 end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :responses, as: :responseable, dependent: :destroy
   ...
end

class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :responses, as: :responseable, dependent: :destroy
   ...
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :responses, as: :responseable, dependent: :destroy
   ...
end
```

I am using CanCan to define my abilities use the Nested Resource feature to authourize the viewing of responses dependent on their parents ability:

```
class ResponsesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorize_parent
  load_resource :post
  load_resource :call
  load_resource :meeting  
  load_and_authorize_resource :response, :through => [:post, :call, :meeting]

  ...

private

  def authorize_parent
    authorize! :read, (@post || @call || @meeting)
  end

end
```

All the abilities are working as they should using the standard actions in the controller.

**However**, I have an action in my Responses controller that is used to poll for new responses by a JS script every 15 seconds:

```
def polling
   current_user_id = params[:current_user_id]
   responseable_type = params[:responseable_type]
   klass = [Post, Call, Meeting].detect { |c| responseable_type == c.name }
      @responseable = klass.find(params[:responseable_id])
   undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_integer = params[:after]
   undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal = (undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_integer).to_d
   divided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal = (undivided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal / 1000000).to_d
   @responses = @responseable.responses.where("created_at > ? AND user_id <> ?", Time.at(divided_millisecond_epoch_time_in_decimal), current_user_id)
end
```

No matter what I try I can not get this to work. I.e. I just get the response "*You are not authorized to access this page*". I presume that I need to add something to get this custom action working, but I'm a bit lost as to where and what.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Added the details in my abilities file:**

```
if user.role == "client"
  can :index, Post, :user_expert_private => false
  can :index, Post, :user_expert_private => true, :user_id => user.id
  can :show, Post, :user_expert_private => false, :countries => { :id => user.country_ids}
  can :show, Post, :user_expert_private => true, :user_id => user.id
  can :create, Post
  can :edit, Post, :user_id => user.id
  can :update, Post, :user_id => user.id
  can :read, Response
  can :create, Response
  can :polling, Response
  can :read, Call, :user_id => user.id
  can :create, Call, :user_id => user.id
  can :edit, Call, :user_id => user.id
  can :update, Call, :user_id => user.id
  can :read, Meeting, :user_id => user.id
  can :create, Meeting, :user_id => user.id
  can :edit, Meeting, :user_id => user.id
  can :update, Meeting, :user_id => user.id
  can :responses, :polling          
  can :posts, :autocomplete
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions), at the end of your polling method, you should be able to place this at the end of your polling method:

```
authorize! :read, @responses
```

I believe the reason is that you have authorized use of the Response object only under the auspices of the parent objects.

edit based on abilities:

perhaps something like

```
can :polling, Response, :user_id => user.id
```

I am doing some work in another project, and [this page is probably going to be of use](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources#nested-through-method).  I will update this answer if/when it proves to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I don't think that's it. I tried and no change. I've updated the question with my ability.rb file. Perhaps that might help you give me a nudge on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: BetjaminRichards I'm going through the same thing. @ScottHelm, this was a good suggestion but it doesn't work in my case either. My case is slightly different I'm looking around now and may post a separate question if necessary. But cancan and polymorphic just isn't working as needed for me when trying to access my Photo>index action, where my Photo klass is polymorphic

Comment: you know i'm still not sure what i did to make it work? i was using the same approach as you using a `before_filter :authorize_parent` function, except in my function instead of just `authorize! :read, (@post || @call || @meeting)`, i use `authorize! :manage, (@post || @call || @meeting)` -- and not sure why it's been so long since i reviewed this code. perhaps would be good to remove all permissions restraints along the chain though (using :manage instead of :read) while in your dev environment to see if you can track down where the error is coming from...